# Monitor doesn't accept connection from DVI to HDMI

Tags: windows-10, video, display, adapter, lg-monitor

I have 2 monitors, an LG Ultragear 24GN600 and an old monitor (LG 24MT49DF-PS), which has an HDMI and AV port. My PC (no GPU) has an HDMI and a DVI port.

The ultragear accepts signals from both direct HDMI and from the DVI adapter (though limited to only 60Hz, instead of 144hz that I get directly from HDMI)
The old monitor accepts signal only from direct HDMI, using the adapter shows no signal (not even a detection from Windows)

Tried changing cables, restarting the PC and the monitor but nothing.

What can I do?

Comment: Which type of DVI (see here the types https://www.404techsupport.com/2014/08/21/dvi-types/) is the cable, the Ultragear, and the old monitor?

Comment: HDMI is downward compatible with DVI, DVI is not upward compatible to HDMI.

Comment: Both the adaptor and the port coming from the Motherboard are DVI-D.
If DVI is not upward compatible to HDMI, how can I get a signal on the new monitor with the same setup? (DVI port -> DVI Adapter -> HDMI cable -> HDMI port in the monitor)

Comment: You might have to use an [active DVI to HDMI converter](https://www.startech.com/en-gb/display-video-adapters/dvi2hd)